# Buttons fill vertical space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I was told that I could use a second linear layout in such a way that my buttons would stretch to fill the remaining empty space vertically. I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="2" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/three"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="3" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/four"
            android:text="4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/five"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="5" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/six"
            android:text="6"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want the buttons to fill up the available height on the screen. In that case please look to the answer here [Android TableLayout height does not fills the whole screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635393/android-tablelayout-height-does-not-fills-the-whole-screen)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/one"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/two"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="2" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/three"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="3" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/four"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="4" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/five"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/six"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="6" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Notice that the table rows now have

```
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 android:layout_weight="1"
```

This will allow the row to expand to fill the remaining space (with each row getting 1/3 of the screen height).

I also changed the buttons layout width to 0dp, as you are using weight. Also you do not need the  `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` 3 times. You only need it on the parent layout.

Finally, as many of your buttons are using the same styling. I'd suggest you look at possibly using a style for these buttons. You can learn more about styles / themes at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html.

Answer (score 2):

I think the function you are looking for is android:weightSum.
Here is the official reference:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#attr_android:weightSum

So to expand your table layout to full screen you need to assign a weightSum of 3 to your TableLayout and divide android:layout_weight of 1 to each TableRow. That will give you the desired result.

So your xml layout file will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TableLayout

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/one"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/two"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="2" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/three"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/four"
        android:text="4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/five"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="5" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/six"
        android:text="6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Hello Mr.Exception-al I don't have 50 rep as of now to put a comment on his question to elaborate on his question. What you suggent I do. Nothing? Above it your -ve vote is not helping the cause either. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Manu, unfortunately the rules of this site states that you should do nothing in this case.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that. Will update my answer with something that I think he is looking for. :)

Comment: Meanwhile I suggest you delete this answer (so you don't lose reputation) and post a new one when you come up with a solution that can help the OP.

Comment: Hello, Exception-al I have updated my answer with something which the asker might be looking for. Thanks!